# How to pass data from MySQL to Google Maps

Tags: php, html, mysql, maps

I'm confused about how to pass data from PHP to my google maps API.

```
<script>

  <?
        $dbFirst = new database;
        $dbFirst->query("SELECT getLatitude,getLongitude FROM t_report
                         WHERE phoneNumber='$idimei' AND tanggal BETWEEN '$tgl1 00:00:00' and '$tgl1 23:59:59' AND (km IS NOT NULL AND km !='') ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");  
        $rowFirst=$dbFirst->tampilkan();

        while ($rowFirst=$dbFirst->tampilkan()){
            $lat=$rowFirst['getLatitude'];
            $lon=$rowFirst['getLongtitude'];
        }
    ?>
    var marker;

    function initMap() {

        var mark1 = {lat:X, lng:Y};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: mark1,
            zoom: 18

        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mark1,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    }
    function toggleBounce() {
        if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }
  </script>
```

how do I put `$lat` and `$lon` to my mark1 X and Y variable? I'm confused on how to pass data outside PHP.
Thanks for answering

Comment: try to access your php data variables or objects to javascript and then make js only to load map and use those data variables in required fields in javascript. that is effective way. as google map apis are builtin in js better than any other language.

Comment: @AjayKumar thanks for your advice. my longitude is null because i said it longtitude, not longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to pass data from PHP variable to JS
Suppose this is where you are querying data from DB and storing it in a variables **$lat** and **$lon**

````
<?php
//data from DB
$lat = "xx.xx";
$lon = "xx.xx";
?>

<script>
// then echo it into the js
// and assign to a js variable
let lat = '<?php echo $lat ;?>';
let lon = '<?php echo $lon ;?>';
// then
 function initMap() {

        var mark1 = {lat:lat, lng:lon};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: mark1,
            zoom: 18

        });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mark1,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    }

</script>```
````

Comment: i tried this, it cause my maps go blank(grey area) but there still pointer of hands dragging map. did my $lat and $lon is null?

Comment: Yes, I think one of the reasons could be $lat and $lon being null. Can you put console.logs in JS code to check if you are getting values from DB?

Comment: thanks mate, i've been figured it out. my table in database and when i called in $rowFirst are different. your code works perectly

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote if you think my answer was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass variable `$lat` and `$lon` from PHP to `X` and `Y` in javascript you can do like this:

```
var marker;
var X ="<?php echo $lat; ?>";
var Y ="<?php echo $lon; ?>";
```

or more shorter:

```
var marker;
var X =<?$lat?>;
var Y =<?$lon?>;
```

Comment: i tried this, it cause my maps go blank(grey area) but there still pointer of hands dragging map. did my $lat and $lon is null?